# Concatenate Values in Microsoft Access

Tags: microsoft-access, database

I have a table with two columns. The first has duplicates (column A), and the second (column B) does not.

I want to query the table in such a way that my result has unique values for A, and their corresponding values in B are all the values in B that were beside the duplicates in A.

To illustrate with a table,

```
A         B
food      spaghetti
food      cucumber
car       ford
car       honda
food      pickle
```

Would become:

```
A         B
food       spaghetti,cucumber,pickle
car        ford,honda
```

I'm working in Access (despite having little experience) because I have too many rows to work in Excel.

Comment: How are you querying the data? Are you running an Access query? Or using Excel to query the table? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What I did in Excel was built a dictionary and when the key existed, I appended the new value to the existing one.  From Access though, I've been trying to think how something similar would be done, but then I realized it isn't iterative.

Comment: So you are trying to run an Access query then?

Comment: Yes, I've moved my data to Access.  I have a feeling such a simple query would only be a few lines, I'm just not sure where to start.

Comment: Getting the unique values is quite simple by either using `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`. The first will likely be more useful. See also [GROUP BY to combine/concat a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154644/group-by-to-combine-concat-a-column). The resulting query isn't going to be all that easy though.

Comment: Great places to start! thank you @Seth and At McDonald's